# Jquery Function call again in the same function

Tags: jquery, post, call

```
function start(){
    var id      = $("#MUChooseMitarbeiter option:selected").val();
    var monat   = $("#MUChooseMonat option:selected").text();
    var jahr    = $("#MUChooseJahr option:selected").text();

    $.post("interface/GET/stundenSELECT.php",{'id':id,'monat':monat,'jahr':jahr}).done(function(data) {
        $('.Content, .Print').html(data);
        $('input[type="text"]').focus(function(){this.select();});
        $('button').button();
        $('#abgabezeit').attr( "title", "Wenn die Zeit um ist sind keine Eintragungen oder Änderungen mehr möglich!" ).tooltip(); 
        $('#status').attr( "title", "Bei 30/30 oder 31/31 wird der Kontoübertrag mit deinem Stundenkonto verrechnet." ).tooltip();
        $('#urlaub').attr( "title", "Urlaubstage die du in diesem Monat genommen hast" ).tooltip(); 
        $('#konto').attr( "title", "Bezieht sich nur auf den aktuellen Monat. Rot=nicht gespeichert | Grün=gespeichert | siehe auch oben Fortschritt-Info" ).tooltip(); 
        $('#auszahlen').attr( "title", "Anzahl in Stunden, die du ausbezahlt haben möchtest" ).tooltip(); 
            $('.tm').change(function(){
            var tm = $(this).val();
            var ta = $(this).parents('tr').find('.ta').val();
            if( !ta || !tm ){ $( "#hTouren" ).dialog( "open" ); }
            var tag = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
            var id  = $("#MUChooseMitarbeiter option:selected").val();
            $.post("interface/POST/stundenUPDATE.php",{'id':id,'tm':tm,'ta':ta,'tag':tag});
        });
        $('.ta').change(function(){
            var ta = $(this).val();
            var tm = $(this).parents('tr').find('.tm').val();
            if( !ta || !tm ){ $( "#hTouren" ).dialog( "open" ); }
            var tag = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
            var id  = $("#MUChooseMitarbeiter option:selected").val();
            $.post("interface/POST/stundenUPDATE.php",{'id':id,'tm':tm,'ta':ta,'tag':tag});
        });
        $('input[type="text"]').change(function(){
             var name = $(this).attr("name");
             var std = $(this).val();
             var tag = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
             var id  = $("#MUChooseMitarbeiter option:selected").val();
             $.post("interface/POST/stundenUPDATE.php",{'id':id,'name':name,'std':std,'tag':tag});
            });
            $('.StundenEnd input[type="text"]').change(function(){
                $('#MUShow').button().click(start);
            });
    }); // end done
```

}

I want to call the Function again by .StudenEnd , but nothing happen.
Why?

Comment: You need to be more specific about your question/requirement.

Comment: You should use some of the space taken up by that garbage text to explain your question better.

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
 $('#MUShow').button().click(start);
```

Looks like you are attaching the function "start" as an event handler for button click event. But you said that you need to call this function, why just not simply call it?

```
$('.StundenEnd input[type="text"]').change(function(){
     start();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking all of this out of the start() function:

```
    $('.tm').change(function(){
        var tm = $(this).val();
        var ta = $(this).parents('tr').find('.ta').val();
        if( !ta || !tm ){ $( "#hTouren" ).dialog( "open" ); }
        var tag = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
        var id  = $("#MUChooseMitarbeiter option:selected").val();
        $.post("interface/POST/stundenUPDATE.php",{'id':id,'tm':tm,'ta':ta,'tag':tag});
    });
    $('.ta').change(function(){
        var ta = $(this).val();
        var tm = $(this).parents('tr').find('.tm').val();
        if( !ta || !tm ){ $( "#hTouren" ).dialog( "open" ); }
        var tag = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
        var id  = $("#MUChooseMitarbeiter option:selected").val();
        $.post("interface/POST/stundenUPDATE.php",{'id':id,'tm':tm,'ta':ta,'tag':tag});
    });
    $('input[type="text"]').change(function(){
         var name = $(this).attr("name");
         var std = $(this).val();
         var tag = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
         var id  = $("#MUChooseMitarbeiter option:selected").val();
         $.post("interface/POST/stundenUPDATE.php",{'id':id,'name':name,'std':std,'tag':tag});
        });
    $('.StundenEnd input[type="text"]').change(function(){
            $('#MUShow').button().click(start);
    });
```

It looks to me like you're trying to delegate an "onchange" event on those elements.

Also, if you want to trigger the click event at the end, you have to call it directly without any parameters.

```
$('#MUShow').button().click();
```

You have to have the following somewhere else in the document, however, for that to work.

```
$('#MUShow').click(function(){ start() });
```